# Error reading from database in a web form

Tags: php, html, sql

I'm trying to pull data from the database which matches data from the text box and the code I am using throws an error.

I think there is something wrong with my SQL query, but I'm not sure what.

The error is:

> Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in C:\wamp\www\search.php on line 65

My syntax:

```
<html>
 <head>

   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"  href="style.css"></link> 

   </head>
   <body>
     <form  action="" name="formdownload" method="post">

  <table>
  <tr><td colspan=2><h1>Domestic Flights</h1></td></tr></br>
      <td height=50> From:</td><td><input type="From" name="from" size=30/>
        <tr><td height=50>To: </td><td><input type="To" name="to" size=30/>
        <tr><td><input name="submit" type="submit" value ="Search"></tr></td>
        <table border="1" align="center" id="table1" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
            <tr>
                <th>Flight No</th>
                <th>Flight Company</th>
                <th>Plane Type</th>
                <th>From</th>
                <th>To</th>
            </tr>
            <center>

            <?php

            $submit = @$_POST['submit'];
            $from = @$_POST['from'];
            $to = @$_POST['to'];
            if($submit)
            {
             $select=mysql_query("select * from flight where ffrom='$from'and To='$to'");
            while($row1=mysql_fetch_array($select))

             {
                $FlightNo = $row1['FlightNo'];
                $FlightCompany=$row1['FlightCompany'];
                $PlaneType = $row1['PlaneType'];
                $From =$row1['ffrom'];
                $To =$row1['To'];

            ?>


            <tr>

            <td width="90" align="center">
                <?php echo $FlightNo;?>
            </td>
            <td width="90" align="center">
                <?php echo $FlightCompany;?>
            </td>
            <td width="90" align="center">
                <?php echo $PlaneType;?>
            </td>
            <td width="90" align="center">
                <?php echo $From;?>
            </td>
            <td width="90" align="center">
                <?php echo $To;?>
            </td>

            </tr>
            <?php }}?>
            </table>

  </table>
 </form>
 </div>
  </div>
   </div>


  </div>

 </center>

</body>
 </html>
```

Comment: N.B.: Using `mysql` is no longer recommended. `mysqli` is now the standard.

Comment: Where did you set the $uname variable? I only see $name being set...

Comment: Shouldn't `$uname` be `$name`? And stop using `<center>`.

Comment: what's the url of this code, so we can make some (injection( mysql test? :)

Comment: guys i have edited it.. check .. i gt a new issue now .. :( when i search with 2 variables

Answer (score 1):

You have an error at the line on the variable name :

```
$select=mysql_query("select * from logintbl where name='$uname'");
```

Replace it with :

```
$select=mysql_query("select * from logintbl where name='$name'");
```

EDIT : since your field is named 'uname' in your database, here is the correct code (a little bit more secure with the addition of `mysql_real_escape`) :

```
$select=mysql_query('select * from logintbl where uname="'.mysql_real_escape($name).'";');
```

REEDIT : you want a second parameter but didn't retrieve it in PHP before your query. Your code should be like this then :

```
<html>
<body>
    <form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="" name="formdownload" method="post">
        <table border="1" align="center" id="table1" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
            <tr>
                <th>ID</th>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Password</th>
                <th>User Type</th>
            </tr>
            <center>
        <br/><br/><br/>
            ID: <input type="text" name="idno" /> <br/><br/>
            Name : <input type="text" name="name" /><br/><br/>
            Marks : <input type="text" name="marks" /><br/><br/>

            <input type="submit" name = "submit" value="submit">

        </center>

            <?php

            $submit = @$_POST['submit'];
            $name = @$_POST['name'];
            $idno = @$_POST['idno'];
            if($submit)
            {
             $select=mysql_query("select * from logintbl where uname='$name' and Id='$idno'");
            while($row1=mysql_fetch_array($select))

             {
                $id = $row1['ID'];
                $name=$row1['uname'];
                $pass = $row1['pass'];
                $type =$row1['type'];

            ?>


            <tr>

            <td width="300" align="center">
                <?php echo $id;?>
            </td>
            <td width="300" align="center">
                <?php echo $name;?>
            </td>
            <td width="300" align="center">
                <?php echo $pass;?>
            </td>
            <td width="300" align="center">
                <?php echo $type;?>
            </td>

            </tr>
            <?php }}?>
        </table>
    </form>
</body>
```

I still strongly advise you to filter your variables before making a query with it with `mysql_real_escape`.

Comment: bt $uname in the the column in my database.

Comment: OK then, I've edited my answer, look if it works now :)

Comment: i got it solved .. but i want to now search with 2 fields ..and im getting an error ... i have edited the above script ... the error (Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in C:\wamp\www\search.php on line 65)

Comment: oh wait ..i edited it wrong .. what u put is what i have .. its still givng the error-- Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in C:\wamp\www\search.php on line 65

Comment: it works perfectly fine with one .. but when i put in Id='$idno' it gives that error ..

Comment: Are you sure you test my code? I've added this : "$idno = @$_POST['idno'];". If not, does your edit shows your actual code?

Comment: So... Where is your actual code? And have you *really* tested my code with the addition of $idno = @$_POST['idno'], which should solve your problem?

Comment: wait i'll re post it with wat im using now .. nd what error m getting